# JSONException: Names must be strings

Tags: java, php, android, arrays, json

I am trying to make a Login and Register activity for an android app. The register activity works fine and it can store information into my Sql database hosted on Hosting, but the Login activity gives me this error...

org.json.JSONException: Names must be strings, but {"username":"bryan625","name":"bryan penaloza","sex":"male","age":21,"password":"test"} is of type org.json.JSONObject at character 88 of {{"username":"bryan625","name":"bryan penaloza","sex":"male","age":21,"password":"test"}}

Here is the part that gets the user data in my ServerRequest.java class

I am aware I'm using deprecated code, but I modified the gradle so it works.

```
public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User> {
    User user;
    GetUserCallback userCallback;

    public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback) {
        this.user = user;
        this.userCallback = userCallback;
    }

    @Override
    protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchUserData.php");

        User returnedUser = null;

        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject("{" + result + "}");

            if (jObject.length() == 0) {
                returnedUser = null;
            } else {

                String name = jObject.getString("name");
                String sex = jObject.getString("sex");
                int age = jObject.getInt("age");


                returnedUser = new User(user.username, name, sex, age, user.password);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


        return returnedUser;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(User returnedUser) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        userCallback.done(user);
        super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);

    }
}
```

Here is my php file that this code is calling.

```
<?php
/*server, user, password, databse */
$conn=mysqli_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx","xxx");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$password = $_POST["password"];
$username = $_POST["username"];  

$statement = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
if($statement === FALSE){ die(mysqli_error($conn)); }

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);


mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
//printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($statement));
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $id, $username, $name, $sex, $age, $password);
$user = array ();
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $user['username'] = $username;
    $user['name'] = $name;
    $user['sex'] = $sex;
    $user['age'] = $age;
    $user['password'] = $password;
}

echo json_encode($user);

mysqli_close($conn);
```

?>

I know that I am successfully connecting to the database because it is returning my the array of values I have stored for a specific user, but I can't figure out how to get rid of that error. Thanks!

Comment: Which line causes the error ?

Comment: I'm not sure, it just says at character 88 of {{"username":"bryan625","name":"bryan penaloza","sex":"male","age":21,"password":"test"}}

I posted the error in the question above

Comment: Can you share a snippet with the PHP response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, **simple mistake**.  You will notice that char 88 is the second to last `}` in the json string.  You need to change:
`new JSONObject("{" + result + "}")` to `new JSONObject(result)`.  The encapsulating `{}` are already included by PHP.

Passing your JSON into a JSON validor also points out the issue:

> #### Input:
>
> ```
> {
>     {
>         "username": "bryan625",
>         "name": "bryan penaloza",
>         "sex": "male",
>         "age": 21,
>         "password": "test"
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> #### Output:
>
> ```
> Parse error on line 1:
> {    {        "username"
> -----^
> Expecting 'STRING', '}'
> ```

You added additional brackets to already valid JSON.  The correct JSON object is as follows:

```
{
    "username": "bryan625",
    "name": "bryan penaloza",
    "sex": "male",
    "age": 21,
    "password": "test"
}
```

Comment: ahh thank you, it is not giving me the error anymore but it still isn't doing what I want it to do.. It is supposed to open up a new activity that displays the users info so I guess on to the next error... lol

Comment: Welcome to programming!  *Onto the next error/bug is pretty much the name of the game.* ;)

Comment: Trust me I know the class I'm doing this app for goes like this: "go make an android app and teach yourself the code."

Comment: I am getting, 

Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

do you know why that is?

Comment: I would print out your PHP input.  I suspect you have `[]` (an empty array).  This cannot be converted to an object.

Comment: Yes, on the site where my database and php files are being hosted, when I click on the .php file that is in the question above there is only [] on the page